# How would I update the app state in a React App during a recursive function which is imported from another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a sorting algorithm visualization app, where some of the sorting algorithms are recursive. For this example I will use merge sort. I would like my sorting functions to be in a separate file for better file structure but am having a hard time updating the state using these imported functions.

Here is my App.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import P5Wrapper from 'react-p5-wrapper';
import sketch from './sketches/sketch.js';
import DropdownButton from 'react-bootstrap/DropdownButton';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown'
import ReactBootstrapSlider from 'react-bootstrap-slider'
import "bootstrap-slider/dist/css/bootstrap-slider.css"
import './App.css';


var arrayHelper = require('./helpers/array.js');
var mergeHelper = require('./algorithms/merge.js');


class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    //this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
    this.shuffle = this.shuffle.bind(this);
    this.setAlgo = this.setAlgo.bind(this);
    this.setArraySize = this.setArraySize.bind(this);
    this.mergeSort = this.mergeSort.bind(this);
    this.arraySize = 500;
    this.state = {currentArray: undefined, initialArray: undefined, algo: undefined, arraySize: undefined};

  }

  componentWillMount(){
    //let currentArray, initialArray;
    let arr = arrayHelper.createRandomArray(this.arraySize);
    this.setState({currentArray: arr, initialArray: arr, algo: 'Select Algorithm', arraySize: 500});
  }

  //Shuffles array to new random array
  shuffle(){
    this.setState({currentArray: arrayHelper.createRandomArray(this.state.arraySize)})
  }

  //Sets user-specified search algorithm based on dropdown button onClick 
  setAlgo(selectedAlgo){
    this.setState({algo: selectedAlgo})
  }

  //Sets the user selected array size
  setArraySize(value){
    let arr = arrayHelper.createRandomArray(value);
    this.setState({currentArray: arr, arraySize: value})
  }
  
  //Runs the imported mergeSort function from separate file
  mergeSort(){
    mergeHelper.mergeSort(this.state.currentArray, 0, this.state.currentArray.length-1);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <header class='App-header'>
        <div class='Buttons'>
          <button onClick={this.shuffle}>Shuffle Array</button>
          <button onClick={this.mergeSort}>Sort</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ReactBootstrapSlider
            value={this.state.arraySize}
            change={event => this.setArraySize(event.target.value)}
            //slideStop={this.changeValue}
            step={100}
            max={1000}
            min={100}
            orientation="horizontal"
            reversed={false}
            //disabled="false" 
            />
        </div>
        <div class='Array'>Array Size: {this.state.arraySize}</div>
        <div>
        <DropdownButton alignRight title={this.state.algo} id="dropdown-menu-align-right">
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey='merge'>
          <button onClick={() => this.setAlgo('Merge Sort')}>Merge Sort</button>
          </Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey='bubble'>
          <button onClick={() => this.setAlgo('Bubble Sort')}>Bubble Sort</button>
          </Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey='quick'>
          <button onClick={() => this.setAlgo('Quick Sort')}>Quick Sort</button>
          </Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey='selection'>
          <button onClick={() => this.setAlgo('Selection Sort')}>Selection Sort</button>
          </Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey='insertion'>
          <button onClick={() => this.setAlgo('Insertion Sort')}>Insertion Sort</button>
          </Dropdown.Item>
        </DropdownButton>
        </div>
        <div class='Grid'>
          <P5Wrapper sketch={sketch} 
          currentArray={this.state.currentArray} 
          arraySize={this.state.arraySize}
          ></P5Wrapper>
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }

  
}

export default App;
```

Here is my merge helper file code:

```
//Function to merge two sorted arrays
function merge(array, left, mid, right){
    var n1 = mid - left + 1;
    var n2 = right - mid;
    var leftArray = [];
    var rightArray = [];
    for(let i=0;i<n1;i++){
        leftArray.push(array[left + i]);
    }
    for(let j=0;j<n2;j++){
        rightArray.push(array[mid + 1 + j]);
    }
    var i=0;
    var j=0;
    var k=left;
    while(i<n1 && j<n2){
        if (leftArray[i] <= rightArray[j]){
            array[k] = leftArray[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            array[k] = rightArray[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<n1){
        array[k] = leftArray[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<n2){
        array[k] = rightArray[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}


//Recursively called mergesort function
function mergeSort(array, left, right){
    if(left>=right){
        return;
    }
    var mid = Math.floor((left + (right-1))/2);

    mergeSort(array, left, mid);
    mergeSort(array, mid+1, right);
    merge(array, left, mid, right);
}

module.exports = {merge, mergeSort}
```

The this.state.currentArray must be updated after each call of merge() but cannot be returned each time due to mergeSort() being recursive. Is there a way to pass this.state as a parameter to mergeSort(), updating this parameter in the mergeSort/merge functions themselves?

This is my first question on Stack so please let me know if I have posted too much info or have been to vague. Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this project: https://github.com/Shubh1815/Sorting-Visualizer

Comment: a u trying to create a visualizer, that shows the progress of the "sorting" until done, or just a final result of the sorted array.

Comment: Progress! Showing the final is easy since I can simply return the sorted array after the recursion is done, my issue is showing the updated array in each step. @SelmiKarim I am looking at that now as well, it may hold some good info I just did not want to change my current structure for drawing the array because of this issue